# Tabela angular material sem scroll

Tags: angular, tabela-html, rolamento, angular-material

Estou fazendo uma tabela com angular material, porém quando eu carrego os itens da tabela não aparece um scroll pra eu descer a tela.

Meu HTML está assim:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="table-responsive" id="tabelaDados">
     <tbody>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="NroGsp">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Guia</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ item.NroGsp }}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="TipoGsp">
           <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Tipo</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ item.TipoGsp }}</td>
         </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="NroGspContratado">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Guia Do Contratado</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">
                {{ item.NroGspContratado }}
              </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="NroMovimento">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Protocolo</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">
                {{ item.NroMovimento }}
              </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="DtaAtendimento">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Data de Atendimento</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let guia">
                {{ guia.DtaAtendimento }}
              </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="VlrInformado">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Valor Infomado</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">
                {{ item.VlrInformado }}
              </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="VlrCalculado">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Valor Total</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">
                {{ item.VlrCalculado }}
              </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="NmeCliente">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Cliente</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ item.NmeCliente }}</td>
            </ng-container>

            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="colunasTabela"></tr>
            <tr
              mat-row
              *matRowDef="let myRowData; columns: colunasTabela"
            ></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Meu css está assim:

`#tabelaDados{ overflow-y: auto; }`

Também já tentei usar `overflow-y: scroll` mas também não funcionou.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tente adicionando no css

```
display: block;
width: 350px;
height: 200px;
overflow: scroll;
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Obrigado heloisa funcinou!!!!